# TicTacToe Doesn't Display All Letters

Tags: java

I created a TicTacToe game and I can't figure out why it won't display the last letter when someone wins. Like if you get 3 in a row it will display only the 2 letters but won't display the winning letter if that makes any sense.

TicTacToe Class Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
         Board board = new Board();
         Rules winner = new Rules();

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         int slot;
         int swap = 1;

         System.out.print("Player 1 Name: ");
         String player1 = input.next();
         System.out.print('\f');
         System.out.print("Player 2 Name: ");
         String player2 = input.next();
         System.out.print('\f');

         System.out.print(player1 + ", Choose X or O: ");
         String letter = input.next();
         System.out.print('\f');

         String player1Letter;
         String player2Letter;

        if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
           player1Letter = "X";
           player2Letter = "O";
        } else {
           player1Letter = "O";
           player2Letter = "X";
        }

         System.out.println("This is how each number is set on the board");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("  1 | 2 | 3  ");
         System.out.println("-------------");
         System.out.println("  4 | 5 | 6  ");
         System.out.println("--------- ---");
         System.out.println("  7 | 8 | 9  ");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Each number represents the slot number. For example if you wanted to");
         System.out.println("Place an 'X' or an 'O' in the very middle, you would choose slot 5");
         System.out.println();

        while (true) {
           System.out.print("Type 'begin' to begin: ");
           String begin = input.next();
           if (begin.equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
               break;
           } else if (!begin.equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
               System.out.println();
               System.out.println("Incorrect Syntax");
           }
         }
          while (true) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(1) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(2) + "  | " + board.getPosition(3) + "   ");
            System.out.println("----------------");
            System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(4) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(5) + "  | " + board.getPosition(6) + "   ");
            System.out.println("----------------");
            System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(7) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(8) + "  | " + board.getPosition(9) + "   ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Choose A Slot: ");
            slot = input.nextInt();
            if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {
               board.setPosition(slot, player1Letter);
               swap++;
            } else if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
              board.setPosition(slot, player2Letter);
              swap++;
            }
            if (winner.isWinner(board) == true) {
                if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {  //swap%2 == 1
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print(player2 + " Wins!");
                    break;
                }
                if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print(player1 + " Wins!");
                    break;
                } else if (winner.isWinner(board) == false) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Tie Game");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
        if (winner.isWinner(board) == true) {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setSize(150, 250);
          frame.setTitle("A Simley Face");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          FaceComponent component = new FaceComponent();
          frame.add(component);

          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Board Class Code:

```
public class Board
{ 
    private String position; 
        String topLeft= "1";
        String topMiddle= "2";
        String topRight= "3";
        String middleLeft= "4";
        String middleMiddle= "5";
        String middleRight= "6";
        String bottomLeft= "7";
        String bottomMiddle= "8";
        String bottomRight= "9"; 
    public String getPosition(int pos)
    {
        if (pos == 1)
        {
            return topLeft;//varible of position 1
        }
        else if (pos == 2)
        {
            return topMiddle;//varible of position 2
        }
        else if (pos == 3)
        {
            return topRight;//varible of position 3
        }
        else if (pos == 4)
        {
            return middleLeft;//varible of position 4
        }
        else if (pos == 5)
        {
            return middleMiddle;//varible of position 5
        }
        else if (pos == 6)
        {
            return middleRight;//varible of position 6
        }
        else if (pos == 7)
        {
            return bottomLeft;//varible of position 7
        }
        else if (pos == 8)
        {
            return bottomMiddle;//varible of position 8
        }
        else if (pos == 9)
        {
            return bottomRight;//varible of position 9
        }
        return position;
    }
    public String setPosition(int pos, String value)
    {
        if (pos == 1)
        {
            topLeft = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 2)
        {
            topMiddle = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 3)
        {
            topRight = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 4)
        {
            middleLeft = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 5)
        {
            middleMiddle = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 6)
        {
            middleRight = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 7)
        {
            bottomLeft = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 8)
        {
            bottomMiddle = value;
        }
        else if (pos == 9)
        {
            bottomRight = value;
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

Rules Class Code:

```
public class Rules
{
    private String winner;
    private String threeInARow;

   public boolean isWinner(Board threeInARow) 
   {
       String pos1 = threeInARow.getPosition(1);
       String pos2 = threeInARow.getPosition(2);
       String pos3 = threeInARow.getPosition(3);
       String pos4 = threeInARow.getPosition(4);
       String pos5 = threeInARow.getPosition(5);
       String pos6 = threeInARow.getPosition(6);
       String pos7 = threeInARow.getPosition(7);
       String pos8 = threeInARow.getPosition(8);
       String pos9 = threeInARow.getPosition(9);

       if (pos1.equals(pos2) && pos2.equals(pos3))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos4.equals(pos5) && pos5.equals(pos6))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos7.equals(pos8) && pos8.equals(pos9))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos1.equals(pos4) && pos4.equals(pos7))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos2.equals(pos5) && pos5.equals(pos8))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos3.equals(pos6) && pos6.equals(pos9))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos1.equals(pos5) && pos5.equals(pos9))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else if (pos3.equals(pos5) && pos5.equals(pos7))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else 
       {
           return false;
       }

    }
}
```

FaceComponent class Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class FaceComponent extends JComponent
{  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      // Recover Graphics2D 
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // Draw the head
      Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
      g2.draw(head);

      // Draw the eyes
      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(25, 70, 15, 15);
      g2.fill(eye);
      eye.translate(50, 0);
      g2.fill(eye);

      // Draw the mouth
      Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(30, 110, 80, 110);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.draw(mouth);

      // Draw the greeting
      g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g2.drawString("YOU ARE A WINNER", 5, 175);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it won't display the last letter when someone wins.

This is happening because in your `main` method, after you have received the user input, you are changing the location selected by user to to letter of the player. Then you are going on to check if the player is a winner or not. If the player is not a winner then you go on to draw the board and wait for the next player input. But if the player is a winner then you simply display the message and exit the loop without redrawing the board.

The solution is you could draw the board again inside the `if` condition of checking the winner then display the message and exit the loop.

I would suggest that you declare a method say draw board in your class `TicTacToe` as shown below:

```
private void drawBoard(Board board){
    System.out.print('\f');
    System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(1) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(2) + "  | " + board.getPosition(3) + "   ");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(4) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(5) + "  | " + board.getPosition(6) + "   ");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(7) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(8) + "  | " + board.getPosition(9) + "   ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now change your `while` loop for drawing the board and getting user input from:

```
      while (true) {
        System.out.print('\f');
        System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(1) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(2) + "  | " + board.getPosition(3) + "   ");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(4) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(5) + "  | " + board.getPosition(6) + "   ");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("  " + board.getPosition(7) + "  |  " + board.getPosition(8) + "  | " + board.getPosition(9) + "   ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Choose A Slot: ");
        slot = input.nextInt();
        if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {
           board.setPosition(slot, player1Letter);
           swap++;
        } else if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
          board.setPosition(slot, player2Letter);
          swap++;
        }
        if (winner.isWinner(board) == true) {
            if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {  //swap%2 == 1
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(player2 + " Wins!");
                break;
            }
            if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(player1 + " Wins!");
                break;
            } else if (winner.isWinner(board) == false) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Tie Game");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

to :

```
      while (true) {
        drawBoard(board); //Replace with draw board
        System.out.print("Choose A Slot: ");
        slot = input.nextInt();
        if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {
           board.setPosition(slot, player1Letter);
           swap++;
        } else if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
          board.setPosition(slot, player2Letter);
          swap++;
        }
        if (winner.isWinner(board) == true) {
            drawBoard(board); // Add the draw board.
            if (swap == 1 || swap == 3 || swap == 5 || swap == 7 || swap == 9 || swap == 11) {  //swap%2 == 1
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(player2 + " Wins!");
                break;
            }
            if (swap == 2 || swap == 4 || swap == 6 || swap == 8 || swap == 10 || swap == 12) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(player1 + " Wins!");
                break;
            } else if (winner.isWinner(board) == false) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Tie Game");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```